# Alien movie about black stones biting people

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

When I was a kid my dad let me watch a movie; I had nightmares for a month. I want to watch it again and can't find it.

It was around 1995, definitely before 2000. At the beginning there was a meteor shower, and a lot of polished black stones fell to earth. When people picked them up a tiny "tongue" bit them and they started turning into aliens. I seem to remember something about their skin going all bubbly and melt-y.

People turned into kind of zombies, they lost their will, the virus or whatever made them want to transform. They could recognize uninfected and tried to infect them (I think with tricking them into touching the stones).

Then some folks developed cure and made it into aerosol and wanted to release it at the gathering where the infected were sort of waiting for the main character to completely turn alien. Anyways, this main guy started to peel his face of (final stage of transformation I think) and his girlfriend released the gas and he died. She survived I think, though she was also infected (that's how she got close in the first place), but still had her own will, though it was shown how she struggled with alien's survival and preservation instinct (because she was infected and that part of her didn't want to release the cure and die).

Also, it was dark movie, I think most scenes were happening at night, pretty much alien/zombie/apocalypse type of feel to it.

Answer (score 8):

Is this the 1997 mini-series [*Invasion*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118452/)?  The summary describes it as:

> Small rocks fall from the sky which, when touched, trigger a latent virus that has always existed in humans and begins mutating them into an alien species. Taking advantage of its hive mentality, the aliens are absolutely dedicated to transforming every human on Earth and do so with alarming swiftness. Only a small group of humans remain who have the medical knowledge to devise antibodies to reverse the effects of the virus.

It's based on a [Robin Cook novel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?574257), the [plot summary for which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_(Cook_novel)) has these details:

> The virus apparently infects all life forms on earth. Meanwhile, the first invasion & infestation having succeeded the disk sends a signal, inviting millions more disks to come. Those who handle the disks receive a sting, soon followed by flu-like symptoms and ending in what could be called "zombie assimilation" into an alien collective consciousness with Beau being the leader.

Comment: Yeah, that look like it could be it, thanks. Never thought to look at series, i had it in my mind that it's a movie

Comment: @Flon: It's a *mini*-series of 175 minutes in total. Depending on where you are, it may well have been marketed as a "movie". For instance, I watched this on German tv, and I'm fairly sure it was categorized as a "tv movie in two parts" rather than as a "series" (even though the latter may be technically correct).