# Late 90s or early 2000s sci-fi film where little rocks fall to earth, prick the fingers of whoever picks them up

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm trying to find a film I saw on TV when I was a kid. Basically, these little rocks fall to the planet, and when you pick them up they prick your finger--and make you do the bidding of whatever sent them. The main character keeps having visions of a small aircraft hanger or something like that. I can't remember if he had to find it or build it, but I think it wanted him to go there.

Anyway, that's all I remember. Anyone know the title?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a live-action movie? What country and language did you see it in?

Comment: It was in the US and in English. I think it might have been on a major network, but I can't remember.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: I have marked this question as a Duplicate. This does not mean that it's a bad question, merely one that we've had before. You will still get upvotes on the question if people vote for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Alien movie about black stones biting people](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243043/alien-movie-about-black-stones-biting-people), might this be the 1997 miniseries *[Invasion](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118452/)*?

> Small rocks fall from the sky which, when touched, trigger a latent virus that has always existed in humans and begins mutating them into an alien species. Taking advantage of its hive mentality, the aliens are absolutely dedicated to transforming every human on Earth and do so with alarming swiftness. Only a small group of humans remain who have the medical knowledge to devise antibodies to reverse the effects of the virus.

Found with a search for `film alien stones bite`

### Trailer

Comment: Yeah, that's what I came up with too.

Comment: Based on the book of the same name by Robin Cook.