# Movie where black shiny rocks fall from the sky and people who touch them start transforming

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, virus

This is a sci-fi movie where at the beginning some little shiny black rocks fall from the sky randomly around a town. All the people that see the rocks and touch them start getting sick, then they start like transforming into like Alien weird type people. At one point in the movie I believe there was an infected kid laying in is bed in his room and then a hole started opening up in his ceiling.I think a meteor came through. The movie was in English I only saw it once at a friends house that had very limited channels on their tv. Seemed like it may have been an older movie but it was in color.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should [edit] your question to add as many details as you remember, especially the bit you noted before about the infected kid and the hole opening in his bedroom ceiling.  Please also include where and when you saw this, what language it was in, etc.

Comment: Note that this user believes that [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243043/alien-movie-about-black-stones-biting-people/278957#278957) is not a match.

Comment: The black rocks make me think of [The Monolith Monsters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monolith_Monsters)

Comment: No, not Monolith Monsters. That’s all I keep finding when I googled my description but for sure not it.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, have you actually watched _Invasion_ (1997) to confirm that it's not the right answer?

Comment: It's almost certainly *Invasion*. Shiny black rocks are a dead giveaway.

Comment: Incidentally, good on you to have posted this as its own question as recommended.

Comment: Does *Invasion* have the scene with the boy having the rock drop through his bedroom ceiling?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I don't know (its a mostly forgettable tv movie, and details scarce, most tuned in for Luke Perry at the time), but the shiny black rocks were virus delivery pods that injected anyone who picked them up.  They came in increasing waves of green shooting stars.  A little extra falling through a roof would be easy.. Or the asker has mixed together two separate scenes from two movies.